# CSS: 3D flip of a single letter

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to achieve is to 3D flip a single letter inside a text.

```
<h1>WebN<span class="text-muted" id="logo-alpha">&alpha;</span>me</h1>
```

In this particular case i want to horizontally flip **α** when it's hovered with the mouse.

I tried doing the same by putting the α in an outside `div` and it works fine, but it doesn't when I try doing the same with the `span` inside `h1`.

This is my CSS:

```
#logo-alpha {

    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

#logo-alpha:hover {

    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Comment: Post your `CSS` code as well.

Comment: Sure, just a moment...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are facing this issue : CSS tranform can't apply on inline elements see here : [dev.w3.org transformable elements](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transforms/#transformable-element) so you need to change the default display property of the `<span>` element to `inline-block`.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/3r7zJ/)**

*CSS :*

```
#logo-alpha{
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
    transition: transform 1s;
}


h1:hover #logo-alpha{
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

Comment: You should probably explain that the `display:inline-block` is the important thing, and why ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol As we don't have the OP's CSS, the issue is hard to guess but it must come from there so it is a good idea, I'll edit my post.

Comment: Your answer's correct, I'm just saying that it only works because you added `display:inline-block`, which OP almost certainly didn't. Without that `display`, the flip doesn't work.

Comment: Just updated the CSS, looks like i missed the `display:inline-block`

Comment: @ShadowBroker yes, here is your updated fiddle with the `display:inline-block;` property.

Comment: Now it works, but my animation is glitchy while your is perfect. Gotta figure that out... thanks for helping by the way :)

Answer (score 2):

Below is some code for both X and Y flips - the important thing is your span needs `display:inline-block` in order for any 3d transformation to be applied.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/J4svf/1/)

HTML

```
<h1>WebN<span class="flipX">&alpha;</span>me</h1>
<h1>WebN<span class="flipY">&alpha;</span>me</h1>
```

CSS

```
span {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(250px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    transform: perspective(250px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    display:inline-block;
}
span.flipX:hover {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(250px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    transform: perspective(250px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
}
span.flipY:hover {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(250px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    transform: perspective(250px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(0deg);
}
```

Comment: Vendor prefix overload! Only `transform` and `-webkit-transform` are needed. Same for `transition` and `-webkit-transition`. And people say Chrome is so much better...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol that is what I thought too but if you look here http://caniuse.com/transforms2d you can see that other prefixes can be needed (for IE9 for example) I'm getting comfused... (edit: sorry missed the paste link, fixed it.)

Comment: Nyeh... `-moz-transform` is "needed" for Firefox 10, but does anyone care about that? `-o-` hasn't been "needed" since Opera 12 (at which point it switched to `-webkit-`). Personally, I like to penalise people who don't update their IE browser by not giving them the same visual beauty as those who do. So my projects will *work*, certainly, but they might not look as nice to people who don't update. Catering to non-updaters only encourages the problem.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - they're the only ones needed for the current gen of browsers sure, depends whats being catered for I guess. I've edited anyway

Answer (score 0):

user hover pseudo class,

```
.text-muted{font-zise:12px;}
.text-muted:hover{font-size:20px; /* opr what ever you want to do when mouse hover*/ }
```

or may be you want something this http://css3playground.com/3d-flip-cards/

try it